# MvxGridView items are vertically overlapping

Tags: android, gridview, xamarin, mvvmcross

So i've succesfully created a MvxGridView with several items with their respective images, some of them have image and some dont. The problem is that when the view is shown, the appear overlapped vertically.

This is the grid layout:

```
    <Mvx.MvxGridView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/cav_gridArticulos"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="4dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="4dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Articulos"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/catalogoarticulos_itemst" />
```

The ItemTemplate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Mvx.MvxImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        local:MvxBind="ImageUrl UrlImagen"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nombre"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            local:MvxBind="Text IdGrupoProducto"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            local:MvxBind="Text Descripcion" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            local:MvxBind="Text PrecioUnitario"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Why is this happening?

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJxTx.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Please post item xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the easy fix is to set the height of the layout explicitly. For different aspect ratio images i used the android:scaleType="centerInside". The only issue would be if i use other device and the screen size changes. But it works fine for now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border">
    <Mvx.MvxImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="180dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        local:MvxBind="ImageUrl UrlImagen; DefaultImagePath DefaultImage"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```